# How to pass data from a model (MVC) to @url.Action() to plot a chart

Tags: c#, html, razor

I want to plot a pie chart. The chart data is in a model/controller. And I have a `@Url.Action()` to display the pie chart. How to pass the chart data from model to `@Url.Action()` here - eventually plotting that data on pie chart?

I'm new to MVC methods and C#. Any help would be highly appreciated.

MyHtml.cshtml

```
@model Project.Models.Data

<body>
    <!-- Display Chart in Partial View Ctrl -->
    <!-- Url.Action ( <ActionName>, <Controller Name> ) -->
    <p><img src="@Url.Action("ShowChart","AssetHistory")" alt="Chart" /> </p>
</body>
```

Controller.cs

```
// Partial View for Pie Chart
        public ActionResult ShowChart()
        {
            var ChartData = new[] { "95", "5" }; // hard coded data //

//            return PartialView("Chart");
            return PartialView ( "Chart", ChartData );
        }
```

MakeChart.cshtml

```
@* @model Project.Models.Data *@
@model IEnumerable<string>

<!-- Model Data Inherited from Parent View  ?? -->

@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Overall Equipment Effectiveness")
    .AddSeries(
        chartType: "Pie",
        name: "OEE",
        xValue: new[] { "ON", "OFF" },
 @*       yValues: new[] { "25", "75" } ) *@
        yValues: Model)
    .Write();
}
```

Comment: What does your controller method look like?

Comment: Well it depends...what kind of data. All `Url.Action` does is generate a URL, nothing particularly magic happens there. What url do you want to generate?

Comment: I have edited my post and added controller.cs. Please have a look Andyb952.

Comment: If you only look for set 2 value or number or integer, you can setup routing so it can handle number or integer in url.

Comment: I have a variable "public double OEE_Percent;" in my "IdentityModels.cs". I need the value of the OEE_Percent to be plotted in the pie chart.

Comment: Hi Anirudha Gupta, I didn't get you sorry. Can you explain?

Comment: Liam, I have added more code in. Please see if you  can make sense of it all now.